# Python: replace 20% of a list

Tags: python, list, random

I am trying to randomly replace 20% of a list in python:

```
ls = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
ls = [1, 2, NULL, 4, 5, 6, NULL, 8, 9, 10]
ls = [1, 2, 82, 4, 5, 6, 28, 8, 9, 10]
```

so far

```
while n <= len(ls)/5
    ls[randint(0, 9)]=randint(1, 100)
    n += 1
```

but it has a fairly large chance of removing and replacing the same entry multiple times in one run.

Comment: Do you want to replace exactly 20% of the contents of the list, or do you want to replace each element independently with 20% chance (so that, on average, 20% of the elements of the list are replaced)?

Comment: I need to replace exactly 20% of the contents each run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming `ls` could be anything, I would recommend generating a list of indices, corresponding to `ls`. Then, you may use [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample) to pick up 20% of those indices, and then alter those only.

From the docs:

> Return a k length list of unique elements chosen from the population
>   sequence. Used for random sampling without replacement.

```
In [816]: for _i in random.sample(range(len(ls)), len(ls) // 5):
     ...:     ls[_i] = random.randint(1, 100)
     ...:     

In [817]: ls
Out[817]: [1, 92, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 75, 10]
```

Comment: You don't have to convert the range into a list.

Comment: @skrx Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 1):

Unless your lists are very large, you can select a sample from the indexes. For example:

```
for idx in random.sample(range(len(ls)), len(ls)/5):
    ls[idx]=random.randint(1, 100)
```

Comment: This fails in 3.x since k must be given as an integer, but division in 3.x converts to floats.

Comment: Just change `len(ls)/5` to `len(ls)//5` to make it Python 3 compatible.

Answer (score 1):

You can [shuffle](https://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.shuffle) a range of indexes and then take first `n` indexes that has to be changed.

```
from random import shuffle
x = [[i] for i in range(10)]
shuffle(x)

#change x[0], x[1], .. x[n-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to eliminate the chance of the same index getting replaced the second time, you can store the result of `randint(0, 9)` in a variable. In the next iterations, use an `if` condition to check if `randint()` returned the same index as the previous iteration. If yes, then continue and do not increment `n`.

Alternatively, you can use `random.sample()` to pick up a given number of samples - 20% of the list size in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Best option would be to pick 20% worth of indexes and then replace them in the list. Something like:

```
from random import randint
twenty_percent = round(len(ls) / 5)
for i in range(twenty_percent):
    ls[randint(0, len(ls) - 1)] = randint(1, 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

**This answer takes INDEX into account, so it won't replace the same value twice.**

```
ls = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
n = len(ls)

x = round(n/5)

for i in range(x):
    index = randint(0, n)
    del ls[index]
    ls.insert(index, randint(0, 100))

print(ls)
```

Works for me. See if it does the job.